# C# When is TextBox.Text.Length < TextBox.SelectionStart

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, textselection

While implementing a [Behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.behavior(v=expression.40).aspx) for a TextBox in WPF, I saw numerous examples, that use the PreviewTextInput event to handle new input. Some of the examples (e.g. [techqa.info](http://techqa.info/programming/question/19535778/validating-decimal-number-on-previewtextinput-of-textbox)) have a condition implemented that I don't understand:

```
if (textBox.Text.Length < textBox.SelectionStart)
    text = textBox.Text;
```

From an outside perspective there is no possibility to have the selection start bigger than the length of a text in the TextBox. At most it can be at the end of the text. As the selection start is zero based, then the length and selection start must be the same value.
Maybe this condition handles a special case?

Comment: Just a guess - Isn't your special case CR-LF handling? See [this remark](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2)

Comment: I dont't think that it is the case mentioned in the msdn, because it changes the SelectionLength and has nothing to do with die SelectionStart. I tested it: If you but the SelectionStart in between CR-LF, it is automatically placed after the CR-LF.

Comment: @vasek `Text.Length` would still be bigger as it counts the LineFeed and isn't zero based.

Comment: Maybe [blindmeis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355239/blindmeis?tab=profile) can open our eyes. Hi wrote the code.